# Application connection to database fails, but works through Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql-server

What could be the problem when in vs.net I can open a connection to SQL-Server, but when trying to do it in a WPF application it fails with the following error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException occurred   HResult=0x80131904
>   Message=A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)

Failed connection attempt code:

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection();
myConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;";
myConnection.Open();
```

So this works fine when connecting through Visual Studio on the same computer, but the application fails.

Any ideas?

Screen: [vs.net connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAdCE.png)

Comment: Can you post  screenshots of the connection dialog pages from Visual Studio?

Comment: Where is the application in relation to the SQL Server?

Comment: Screen added, the application is local and the SQL-Server is on a server, vpn inbetween. Connection works in vs.net, but not in the running application.

Comment: The error message clearly states that you've supplied an invalid connection string. Try copying the one generated from Visual Studio, or even better, use [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx). Also, check the possible [connection string parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I've tried SqlConnectionStringBuilder with the same parameters as I'm using in Server Explorer and it still doesn't work. I'm still thinking it has to do with some difference between an application and Server Explorer in vs.net.